# WPF combobox binding from code behind

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, code-behind

How can I bind an `IList` item to a `ComboBox` through the codebehind.cs file.
Please explain with simple steps.

I need the steps for two way binding, not by setting `ItemsSource`.

I need something like:

```
myComboBox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, 
                      new Binding { Source = myList });
```

but I need the `SelectedItem` also.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean something like this?

```
myComboBox.SetBinding(
   ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, 
   new Binding { Source = myList });

myComboBox.SetBinding(
   Selector.SelectedItemProperty,
   new Binding("SelectedItem") { Source = mySelectedItemSource});
```

Comment: @nag, Thanks for pointing that out - I've corrected the code snippet.