# How to set WPF Combobox SelectedValue by code behind based on the custom class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to select custom item under WPF Combobox by code behind. For example: "Spanish"

```
 UILanguages languages = new UILanguages();                
                languages.Add(
                        new UILanguage
                        {
                            Culture = "en",
                            SpecCulture = "en-US",
                            EnglishName = "English"
                        });

                languages.Add(
                    new UILanguage
                    {
                        Culture = "es",
                        SpecCulture = "es-ES",
                        EnglishName = "Spanish"
                    });

                CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource
                {
                    Source = languages
                };

                cmbLanguages.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = cvs });
```

Markup

```
  <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" 
              Name="cmbLanguages" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UILanguagesViewSource}}" 
              />
```

Please, note that

but this 
[Set SelectedItem of WPF ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391195/set-selecteditem-of-wpf-combobox)
and this
[WPF combobox binding from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193627/wpf-combobox-binding-from-code-behind)
doesn't help at all.

Any clue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to set the SelectedValue property to the specific instance of your language.  This could be done via something like:

```
// Get first element with proper name from the bound source
cmdLanguages.SelectedValue = languages.FirstOrDefault(l => l.EnglishName == "Spanish");
```

Comment: Thank you Master. Your solution is elegant one!(+1)!!

Answer (score 1):

Or in addition to Reed's asnwer you can (*pseudocode*), first bind to a property

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Selected}" />
```

In your `UILanguage` have a boolean property `Selected`

and from code behind do, something like this

```
UILanguage lang = languages.FirstOrDefault(l => l.EnglishName == "MyLanguage");
lang.Selected = true;
```

//update binding

Definitely more code, but pure `WPF` coding, in this case.