# C# change the selected index of a ComboBox item using LINQ

Tags: c#, uwp

Im not sure if the title represent the problem I have. The explanation here below should be clearer.

I cannot get my code to select the correct value in the ComboBox with the data from my List. I checked for similar problems here in SO but after reading several I cannot find one that matches my problem.

I fill the list with the follwing code:

```
if (roleComboBox.SelectionBoxItem.Equals("Player"))
            {
                memberID++;

                Player player = new Player(memberID, team, firstName, lastName, age, salary, yearsActive, position, minutesPerGame);

                players.Add(player);              

                PrintList();
            }
```

Now I want to retrieve the data from the List and put it back into the TextBox/ComboBox it came from so I can change the data and put it back into the List (kinda a modify option). I have a different ComboBox with where I select an ID which matches a memberID which in its turn retrieves the data from the List. I use the following code for that:

```
private void ModifyComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int modifyID = int.Parse(modifyComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        var player = players.Where(p => p.memberID == modifyID);

        teamComboBox.SelectedValue = player.Select(p => p.team).FirstOrDefault(); // this isnt working as intended
        firstNameTextBox.Text = player.Select(p => p.firstName).FirstOrDefault(); 
        lastNameTextBox.Text = player.Select(p => p.lastName).FirstOrDefault();
        ageTextBox.Text = player.Select(p => p.age.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        salaryTextBox.Text = player.Select(p => p.salary.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        yearsActiveTextBox.Text = player.Select(p => p.yearsActive.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        minutesPerGameTextBox.Text = player.Select(p => p.minutesPerGame.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

While the TextBoxes get filled with the correct data the ComboBox just gets blank.

This is de XAML code for the ComboBox if needed:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="teamComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">-Choose a team-</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Minnesota Timberwolves</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Charlotte Hornets</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>LA Lakers</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: How about binding your teamComboBox's SelectedValue to a variable, and then programmatically updating that variable, [such as from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916325/3791245)?  Otherwise, you should really be pulling from the original list of values given to the ComboBox, instead of creating a new object from the `player`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the type of SelectedValue needs is ComboBoxItem instead of the string type you passed. If you want to set the SelectedValue programmatically, you can set the [SelectedValuePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_Selector_SelectedValuePath) of teamComboBox as "**Content**" first, it means to set/get the Content of the ComboBoxItem(ie the string you set for the ComboBoxItem). Then you can set your p.team to SelectedValue. For example:

.xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="teamComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectedValuePath="Content" Margin="200,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">-Choose a team-</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Minnesota Timberwolves</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Charlotte Hornets</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>LA Lakers</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thx, that did the job. What does “Content” in the SelectedValuePath exactly do? Cant find anything about it in the MS docs.

Comment: SelectedValuePath is equivalent to a path, which points to the property of the current SelectedItem. In general, the SelectedItem is a ComboBoxItem, but currently what you need is the data you passed to the ComboBoxItem, you can get the data via ComboBoxItem.Content property.  So set the SelectedValuePath to Content.